# "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error with JSON serialization

Tags: ios, json, xcode, serialization, sigabrt

I'm trying to parse weather data into my App with Xcode 7.3.1, iOS 9.3 and JSON by using Weather Underground API (but I get the same problem with other APIs such as OpenWeatherMap).

I don't get error when I build my app but when I call the weather in the Simulator I get a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error. I used breakpoint to speculate that my problem come from the Serialization.

I have already tried to clean my project and I didn't have double connections.

When I download and run the project of [this](http://www.appcoda.com/weather-watchkit-app/) tutorial  I have the same problem...

Here is my code :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *affichermeteo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *meteo;

@end



@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (IBAction)affichermeteo:(id)sender {

NSData *allCoursesData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                              [NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://api.wunderground.com/api/e5cdee14984e242b/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json"]];

NSError *error;

NSDictionary *allCourses = [NSJSONSerialization
                            JSONObjectWithData:allCoursesData
                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                            error:&error];



if( error )
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else {
    NSArray *currentobservation = allCourses[@"estimated"];
    for ( NSDictionary *theCourse in currentobservation )
    {
        _meteo.text=theCourse[@"weather"];

    }
}



}



@end
```

My error window :

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDgJ9.png)

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for my english, I am french !

Comment: Which line is crashing? And can you edit your question to add the stack trace from the crash? (You may need to set a breakpoint on exceptions in order to tell which line is causing the crash.)

Comment: The crash appears at the " options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers" line.

Comment: That suggests that the server is giving you badly formed JSON. Can you feed the contents into a different JSON parser or JSON validator?

Comment: And BTW, your code for reading the JSON from the server is not going to work for a production app. `NSData` `initWithContentsOfURL` is a synchronous call, and it will cause the UI to freeze until the data is completely loaded. If there is a network hiccup, that freeze can be as long as 2 minutes, and the system will kill your app. You will need to change that code to use NSURLSession.

Comment: Yes, online JSON parser show me the JSON content without any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get data using your code. You are missing the iOS 9's newly added  App Transport Security flag.

Add the ***App Transport Security Settings*** key and mark ***Allow Arbitrary Loads*** to ***YES*** like in the screenshot below:

[image]

This should solve your problem.

Check [this](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) link to learn more about App Transport Security.